# Eclipse building the code again and again (without any changes)?

Tags: java, eclipse, solaris, eclipse-indigo

I am noticing a strange issue with Eclipse Indigo. It is Building Workspace again and again even though there is no change in the code!

In Progress bar it prints

```
Building Workspace 44%
..
Building Workspace 10%
..
Building  Workspace 33%
```

Any idea what is going on here? For the time being I have unchecked the 'Build Automatically' flag.

Comment: You might need to find an optimal build order for your projects if you have several projects

Comment: It could be one of the plugins/sub-modules modifying your workspace in a way you did not expect. Eclipse can get really complicated when too many components are being used together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried the following trick couple of times and this seems to work more often than not:

1. Uncheck `Build Automatically` flag
2. Refresh all the projects in the workspace
3. Re-enable the automatic build after sometime by checking the `Build Automatically` flag

Note that as I mentioned earlier this is a trick and not a resolution. But, hope others facing these issues will find this helpful.

Comment: I'll add that after unchecking `Build Automatically` and force-closing eclipse, it still hung when I rechecked it. I had to make sure eclipse could close normally, then start up and check `Build Automatically` and it finally stopped hanging.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have noticed that too and it can be rather annoying.  I have reverted to manual compiling in Eclipse by switching auto-building off (under project).

Compiling manually is a bit old-school, but it works for me.  I prefer to compile, package and test the code at the command line using maven.

(I'll probably get a downvote for this approach (i.e. not using integrated tools, etc.), but it works for me and it works well! At least I'm not using VIM for coding Java! :))

Comment: You might get a downvote because maven is considered an integrated tool in some ways

Comment: -1 For the opinions and other blabla. You could put this answer in a one-liner 'try manual compiling or maven'...

Comment: @Ishtar... whao dude. Thanks for your opinion and your blah-blah.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 7, then the Windows indexing in some directories can cause automatic rebuilds in Eclipse: see Bug 342931 - [Windows 7 Libraries trigger rebuilds](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342931).

Comment: Thanks Matthew ! But actually I am not using Win7 but rather using Solaris